# Topological quantum computation : Anyon model

Tags: condensed-matter, specific-reference, notation, anyons

Could someone tell me about Frobenius-Schur indicator and the associated cups and caps notation in context of anyon model. One possible reference could be Parsa Bonderson thesis which is freely accessible here: http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/2447/2/thesis.pdf